# Set div block at center

Tags: css

I need to set div block in the center of screen, but i don't know how.

```
.pop-up{
    width: 850px;
    height: 640px;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 20%;
    position: fixed;
    top:1%;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

There should be `position:absolute;`.

Comment: Post your html and a fiddle please.

Comment: add right:20%;  but do not specify width?

Comment: margin:auto; may do the trick if the popup is located in a div that takes up the whole screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set position to absolute. and top, bottom,right,left to 0. and then provide fixed width and use margin to auto. this will center the div. importent thing is you need to use fixed width and height. See the demo here. If this is not your solution let me know...

```
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U2FZj)
```

For More info on Positioning follow the bellow link. Below chapter is excellent

[Detailed Positioning](http://learn.shayhowe.com/advanced-html-css/detailed-css-positioning/)

Answer (score 0):

put this in the head:

```
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            doResize();
            $(window).on('resize', doResize);
        });

        function doResize() {
            $('.center').css({
                position:'absolute',
                left: ($(window).width() - $('.center').outerWidth())/2,
                top: ($(window).height() - $('.center').outerHeight())/2
            });
        }
    </script>
```

And give the element in question

```
class="center"
```

that'll do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `<div>` to be right in the centre of the screen, you can use this:

```
.pop-up{
    z-index: 10;
    height: 640px;
    width: 850px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -320px; /* half the height */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -425px; /* half the width */
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

[Here's what it looks like](http://www.cssdesk.com/QUwK9)